# Bidirectional Electronic Relay

Tags: microcontroller, level-shifting

I'm trying to figure out the best way to build a small "wall" of 20 different OBD-2 connectors which would be use to initialize a set of OBD-2 compatible devices.  The situation is that I need to be able to have a user plug in a set of these devices and just walk away and come back later and they have all been initialized.

I've tried dealing with the signaling (and level conversion) necessary to emulate one of the OBD-2 protocols and have given up main due to lack of time.  So I'm looking at using one of these OBD-2 simulator boards, e.g. http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/152464135531

My question is electrically what is the "normal" mechanism for connecting a series of circuits from one pathway to the next? I think only need 4 wires for each device to make this work (a bus plus and minus, an overall 12v+ and overall ground - probably can combine bus minus and overall ground).  But the idea would be to use a Raspberry Pi or Parallax Propeller board to connect the simulator device to the first physical port, wait 2 minutes, then connect it to the second, etc. and so on.

If I use a transistor to trigger the pathway (from 3.3v on the microcontroller to whatever the higher voltage is - 5v for the bus or 12v for the overall power) the flow is essentially one-way, which works for power but not for an actual data wire which is being driven and sensed alternately from both ends.

Is there some normal way this is done?  Perhaps some inexpensive piece of hardware that does this sort of thing that I should be looking at?

Comment: Which "bus" are you specifically referring to, the CAN or the SAE J1850? Maybe a wiring diagram would be helpful (or use the table from the wikipedia article on OBD(-II)!)

Comment: I tried using the SAE J1850 PWM because it looked simpler and the voltage levels seem easier to get right.  That was when I was trying to do the simulation myself.  But if there is a way to pass the signal through more transparently from the separate simulator device, it wouldn't matter, I would just connect the relevant wires at the right time and be done with it.

Comment: well, I don't really know OBD-II well enough, but I'd presume that the SAE J1850 link has different things attached than the CAN Bus, so it's up to you to know how many links you need :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a multiplexer / demultiplexer.

There's a whole series of them within the CD4000 (ancient!) family of ICs; you can also use more modern alternatives. I'd start with something like the CD74HC4067 (74xx series logic – old as time itself, but proven, and most importantly, does the job you need).

Here's a link to [Texas Instrument's Multiplexer product page](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/switches-multiplexers/multiplexer-demultiplexer-products.page#p848=22;24;32), limited to those multiplexers with 22, 24 or 32 bits (i.e. lines). You'd need one of these for each data line you want to switch. Regarding power, I'd simply switch the +Vcc line with a set of high-side MOSFETs (although high-side switching is sometimes a bit of a pain, I think this is the easiest route), potentially addressed by a simple (daisy-chain of) shift register(s), if your controller happens to have too few pins.

In a phase of laziness, and assuming your devices don't draw > 20mA: Use [digital switches](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/switches-multiplexers/digital-switch-products.page?familyAliasId=1203308#p106max=12;18) to switch the 12V on and of.